# Pervasive PSQL 10 Database to MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, pervasive, btrieve

I want to migrate a Btrieve Database to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. I already have done the step of migration to Pervasive PSQL 10 Workstation (x86), which offers an ODBC / OLE DB driver. (It seems Microsof doesn't offer any solution to import Btrieve.)

Ok, so far so good, but how can I transfer the whole database (schema and data) into Microsoft SQL Server? The Import Wizard of SQL Server crashes every time and is useless, because it doesn't map Date- and Memo-Datatypes correctly. I also tried to map these datatypes manually, but the wizard always crashes, caused by ODBC-Errors.

So, I'm looking for a tool which offers a native driver to Btrieve or PSQL 10. It would be nice if it is free, because I only need it for this single migration.

TIA! ^^

Comment: Could you share information on how did you do the first step of migration ?

Comment: @RahulMakwana You have to create Data Definition Files (DDF) which provide all Metadata Pervasive needs. There are several tools for that task, but that also depends how information like fields, used datatypes,... of your source was saved managed. In worst case you have to create them manually by using the DDF-Builder which is provided with your database. But after that you can put the ddf-Files in the same folder like your datafiles and add it as a new database using the Pervasive Control Center, which automatically creates an ODBC-DSN for you.

Comment: Thanks this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool with a Btrieve driver but you still need the DDFs (just like in ODBC) available from Pervasive called Data Integrator.  It is not free but you can find more information at http://integration.pervasive.com/.

Another more manual option would be to export the data from PSQL to CSV, then import the CSV to the MS SQL server.  You would have to manually create the tables in the MS SQL database but it could be done with the tools you have.

Also, you say it's crashing with ODBC errors.  Are the ODBC errors from PSQL or MS SQL?  What are they?